# How do I figure out the names of OutputCache items?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a situation in which across our app, there is a lot of content which can be put in the `OutputCache`, but this content can be refreshed by any user at any point. What I need to do is completely clear the cache when any user instigates the refresh action.

I assumed it would be simple enough, the `HttpResponse` has a method `RemoveFromOutputCache`. However this method takes a string which is the name of the item which has been cached. It does not look like there is any easy way to get a list of item names which have been cached.

As a result I have overriden the `OutputCacheAttribute` with the following class:

```
public class HierarchyOutputCache : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public static readonly ConcurrentBag<string> CachedPages = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

    public HierarchyOutputCache(params string[] varyParameters)
    {
        Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server;
        Duration = int.MaxValue;
        VaryByParam = string.Join(";", varyParameters);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        CachedPages.Add(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

Then when a certain action is hit in my application I can do the following:

> HierarchyOutputCache.CachedPages.ForEach(Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem);

However, the `Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem` isn't working, which I assume is because I am passing an incorrect string with the `RawUrl` I am storing in my attribute.

I cannot find any information anywhere about what this name should be, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I easily solved this by using the following item name in my `HierarchyOutputCache` class:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    CachedPages.Add(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath);
}
```

This meant my call to `HierarchyOutputCache.CachedPages.ForEach(Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem)` worked as expected!